# ember, update form value using jquery

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have an ember app where I show a bootstrap popover.  From that popover, there is a little form that should update the value of a textarea which is bound to a model.  If I type in the textarea, the binding to the model works fine.  However, I if I use jquery (like below) to update the  value of the text area, the ember binding will not see the change in the model.  Is this even possible?

```
$("#myBoundTextArea").val("blah");
```

Comment: maybe try and trigger the change event after

Comment: You should be using the `get` and `set` to trigger bindings. I don't think setting the value with jQuery will do that.

Comment: yeah, the problem is complicated because one of my input fields, is actually an HTML designer, so keeping the DOM of that field in sync with the model has been challenging.

Answer (score 16):

You can trigger the change, using jquery, which also will notify ember binding.

This is done as such

```
$("#myBoundTextArea").trigger("change");
```

Comment: I used this technique to keep two input fields in sync.  The Ember bound field was hidden, and I was setting its value, but without the `trigger('change')`, it didn't work.  Thanks!